# Sql tables design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table with two columns:
`Brand(varchar) | optional_os_type(varchar)`

for example:

```
+--------------+
| Lenovo | 1   |
| Dell   | 2   |
+--------------+
```

Whereas
1 = win8.1
2 = win10

Currently I want to be able to have only one OS type for a given brand, but very likely I will want to be able to have multiple os_type for one Brand.

For example Dell will have both 1 and 2 options.
I thought of my table to look then like that:

```
+---------+------+
| Lenovo  |  1   |
| Dell    |  1,2 |
+---------+------+
```

Is it okay to do so or its more recommended that I'll have two columns  like below:
(added another id coloumn + changing PM key from brand to (brand+optional_os_type)

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| 1   | Lenovo  |       1 |
| 2   | Dell    |  1      |
| 3   | Dell    |       2 |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 3 tables:

1. `brand`
2. `os`
3. `brand_os`

Add the fields that you need to the first 2 tables. The third (`brand_os`) will hold the primary key of `brand` and `os` for every combination that you need. You are now as flexible as you want. No double coding of a `brand` or `os` and when a new `os` arrives you just add it to the `os` table and you can join them to all `brand`s that you want. No need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which might be better:

first table that contains brands ( each brand has 1 row ) , such as :
**create table brands (brand_id number, brand_name , additional columns...)**

second table contains the brand_id's+OS_types , such as :

**create table Brand_OS_Types ( brand_id number , OS_type , additional columns...)**

this table may contain multi rows per brand , you can add foreign key between the tables ( on the brand_id).